# Class argument test in __init__

Tags: python, exception

I have a class `Point` that accepts position, value and flag as arguments. This class should accept only integers as position and value arguments. I tried the code below, but it doesn't work properly.

```
class PointException(Exception):
    pass

class Point():
    def __init__(self, position, value, flag=False):
        try:
            if all([isinstance(x, int) for x in position, value]):
                self.position = position
                self.value = value
                self.point = (position, value)
            self.flag = flag
        except:
            raise PointException("Foo value and position must be integers.")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< {0}, {1}, {2} >".format(self.position, self.value, self.flag)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Point):
            return False
        try:
            return all([self.point == other.point, self.flag == other.flag])
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

**Update**

I get an `AttributError` when I try `Point(1, 1.2)`, for instance.

```
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'position'
```

Comment: Point has the attribute `position` only when the values passed are int, otherwise the if condition fails inside `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if all([isinstance(x, int) for x in position, value])
```

should be

```
if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in (position, value))
```

And more generally you have to `raise` the exception in `__init__`, not catch it with `except`:

```
def __init__(self, position, value, flag=False):
    if not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in (position, value)):
        raise PointException("Foo value and position must be integers.")

    self.position = position
    self.value = value
    self.point = (position, value)
    self.flag = flag
```

There are other areas of improvement that you can read about in the other answers

Comment: Note that this won't always work in Python 2 due to longs (you'd need `isinstance(x, (int, long))`.  BTW: `throw`/`catch`?  I think someone's been using some other language.. ;-)

Comment: `from __future__ import java_syntax` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't really want to do things like this -- you want the responsibility for having the correct type to be with the instantiator, not with the class.

But if you do want to enforce that the numbers be integers, Python has a special module for that: `numbers`.

```
import numbers
isinstance(position, numbers.Integral) and isinstance(value, numbers.Integral)
```

Or, if you must use `all`,

```
all(isinstance(x, numbers.Integral) for x in (position, value))
```

There's no need for the `[]`.